# How to set Info Window on bottom of screen

Tags: android, marker, infowindow

I have some trouble with my custom info window for markers in Google Maps v2.

When the user clicks on marker, I would like to show the info window on bottom of screen with full-width.

Any ideas, how I can do that?

Comment: read this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker there's a sample on how to apply custom markers.

Comment: @Panczur have you succeed or not?

Comment: yeah, I used [link](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html) Bottom Sheets from Design Support Library

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use interesting component introduced in Material Design is the Snackbar. Snackbars are just like Toast messages except they provide action to interact with. Snackbar will be displayed at the bottom of the screen and can be swiped off in order to dismiss them.

[Check this.....](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)

Thanks..

Comment: Thanks, I will probably use taht.